# Which is correct way of using MaxConnectionsPerServer in HttpClientHandler?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to find the correct value for `HttpClientHandler.MaxConnectionsPerServer`.

My services conditions:

- I use `ASP.NET Core 3.1 - 6.0`
- I have many services on a server.
- Services responses for many requests per second.
- Services make requests to other REST services via `HttpClient`.
- Usually `HttpClient` setups via `HttpClientFactory` in `Startup.cs`:

```
services
    .AddHttpClient<IOtherService, OtherService>()
    .ConfigureHttpClient(httpClient => httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler { MaxConnectionsPerServer = 10 });
```

Usually, it works pretty well, but sometimes (in a moment of high load) I get many `TaskCanceledException` and `OtherService` continues to respond as fast as it can. I understand that `HttpClientHandler` reaches the limit of `MaxConnectionsPerServer`.

My questions:

- Is it the correct way of using `MaxConnectionsPerServer`? Maybe I should not use `MaxConnectionsPerServer` anymore?
- How can I find the correct value for `MaxConnectionsPerServer`?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't timing out? You have a very short 3 second timeout here and that will throw a `TaskCanceledException` with an inner `TimeoutException` exception.

Comment: Why are you changing it at all? What problem are you trying to solve by setting it, are you running out of sockets? The default should be fine. Just make sure to dispose everything properly, and you houldn't have an issue. The timeout is also a concern: 3 seconds is too short

Comment: @DavidG Yes, I'm sure. Sometimes my service is timing out, but it is rare. Usually, I see in the log how `OtherService` do his job for milliseconds, but I have timeout anyway, and those services are in the same local network.

Comment: @Charlieface It is part of the legacy code, and I don't know the main reason for setting `MaxConnectionsPerServer`. Right now I'm trying to understand it. So, the main reason for this question is that I started to think to use the default value for `MaxConnectionsPerServer`.

Comment: If you aren't checking the inner exception of your `TaskCancelledException` then you cannot know if they are all timeouts. If you are really hitting the max connections per server, they will likely queue up and time out before even hitting your endpoint.

Comment: @DavidG Yes, I'm trying to check the inner exception. The most popular inner exception is `SocketException - Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.`. I tell about chances, sometimes my service didn't hit `OtherService` but when it hit `OtherService` works fast.

Comment: Update: I have deleted parameter `MaxConnectionsPerServer`. But my service still gets `TimeoutException` when called service executes his job in several hundred milliseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Questions asked by me do not have short answers. The approach described in my question is probably a superficial implementation of [the Bulkhead pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/bulkhead).

My answers:

> Is it the correct way of using `MaxConnectionsPerServer`? Maybe I should not use `MaxConnectionsPerServer` anymore?

It is the correct way if I want to reduce a load on called service (`IOtherService`)

> How can I find the correct value for `MaxConnectionsPerServer`?

I have to collect monitoring data and analyze actual cases if I want to find the correct value for `MaxConnectionsPerServer`. Also, it can change after changing a load on my service or `IOtherService`

Comment: How did you collect data and analyze it? any useful guidelines, I'm trying to check if this is the issue for us, but using `netstat` is not very friendly.